# why gunicorn command not found with gunicorn installed?

Tags: django, gunicorn

I have intalled gunicorn,but gunicorn command not found:

```
# pip3.4 install gunicorn
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): gunicorn in /usr/local/python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages

# gunicorn
-bash: gunicorn: command not found
```

what is the problem,is gunicorn install path not be recognized by system?

Comment: I presume you have installed it to the system and to a venv. Use `locate` to find the gunicorn binary and ensure that directory is within your PATH.

Comment: i am not using venv ,gunicorn is not in my system path,i create a gunicorn in system path and type some code ,then it worked, but why not it is automaticaly included in path?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. What OS are you using?

Comment: production server centos 6.5 x64,that's kind of weird,my development env is virtual machine,the same OS with my production server

Comment: There is probably something screwy with the path. I would check it

Comment: sure,thanks,please keep me updated when you find something~and i'v got  a solution in the posted answer,that's what i can do.

Comment: Are you using Python3?

Comment: yes,python3.4.2 exactly.

Comment: How did you install it? Am I correct in thinking CentOS has python 2 by default?

Comment: yes,the system default python2.6.what i do is :first,i installed python3.4.2 from source **python3.4.2.tar.gz** with cutom path **--prefix=/usr/local/python3.4** ,then i put python3.4 into sys path **/usr/bin/python3.4**, and pip3.4 into **/usr/bin/pip3,4**, second,i installed gunicorn using **pip3.4 install gunicorn**,that' all.

Comment: Okay. Locate the gunicorn executable from the pip install which will be somewhere in /usr/local/python3.4 I would imagine as add the location to your path. Gunicorn is not being picked up because the executable isn't going in to /usr/bin.

Comment: yeah,it seems thing happens as what you say,i recalled that i installed python3.4 in my development server without custom path **--prefix**,but my productions server did,and in dev server **gunicorn** went into **/usr/local/bin/gunicorn** automatically,and i checked my production server,it did locate in **/usr/local/python3.4/bin/**.And,why would this happen?

Comment: Because pip places the files within Pythons bin directory and this needs to be in PATH. You can see this with virtualenv. When you install a package with a binary it goes in to the venv bin. This is auto in path because of the the source command.

Comment: oh,i see,Thanks,Thanks for your time,I very appreciate what you did to me :)

Answer (score 20):

I faced the same issue and it turns out I had to add gunicorn binary path to Linux PATH variable. You can start by echoing $PATH to see all binary path listed on the system. Then find out where gunicorn is installed. For my case I was using python virtual environment and pyenv which helps manage several python versions and dependencies separately.

```
(venv3.6) dave@daverig (develop)✗ % pip show gunicorn
Name: gunicorn
Version: 19.7.1
Summary: WSGI HTTP Server for UNIX
Home-page: http://gunicorn.org
Author: Benoit Chesneau
Author-email: benoitc@e-engura.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/dave/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/venv3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Notice gunicorn is installed in `/home/dave/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/venv3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages` and the corresponding path for the binaries for this particular python version is at `/home/dave/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/venv3.6/bin`. So I had to add that to Linux path via `~/.profile` file like so;

`export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/venv3.6/bin` then ofcourse you want to refresh this using `source ~/.profile` or restart your terminal. Once I was able to do this, gunicorn binary was now available on my console;

```
(venv3.6) dave@daverig (develop)✗ % gunicorn --version
gunicorn (version 19.7.1)
```

Comment: How would one do this from within a deployed Google App Engine instance? I ask because locally, the docker container does have `gunicorn` on the path.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem on Debian.

It turns out that on Debian the [documentation](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/install.html) advises to install gunicorn via apt:

```
$ sudo apt install gunicorn
```

Comment: `sudo apt install gunicorn3` if you are using Python3

Comment: And differences between this and `python3-gunicorn` ?

Comment: There is no `gunicorn3`, it is just alias for `gunicorn` debian package - as I understand it is a /usr/bin/gunicorn wrapper for `python3-gunicorn`!?

Answer (score 6):

Installing `gunicorn` [from source](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/install.html#from-source) saved me after 2 hours trying!

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn.git
```

Answer (score 5):

i just created a file named gunicorn and type these codes below which is the same as my development server , and included it into system path,such as `/usr/bin`

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.4

#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run


if __name__ == '__main__':
        sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$','',sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(run())
```

in this way, it solved my problem,but still confused me,why gunicorn command not generated and included into system path automatically?and why my development server did ,both the same OS (centos 6.5 x64)

Comment: This also happened to me, using a Framework-version of Python 3 on OS X . Thanks for sharing the script!

Answer (score 1):

If you installed python3 from source compiled, you should export your python3 PATH:

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/python3/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
python3 -m gunicorn -c server.py core.wsgi
```

My server.py

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from os import environ


def max_workers():
    return cpu_count()


bind = "0.0.0.0:" + environ.get("PORT", "8080")
max_requests = 1000
worker_class = "gevent"
workers = max_workers()

env = {
    "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE": 'core.settings'
}

reload = True
name = "core"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you use python3.4-venv?

if true

- Delete `env` folder
- Just reinstall: `python3.4-venv`. Ex for ubuntu:
  `apt install python3.4-venv`
- Exec: `python3.4 -m venv env`
- `source env/bin/activate`
- reinstall gunicorn by : `pip3 install gunicorn` or install from `requirements.txt` by `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score -4):

go to terminal and change directory to environment and then type the below command.

```
pip install gunicorn
```

#Enjoy1

Comment: Why was this answer downgraded? It's valid if the OP is trynna install the gunicorn in his/her emvironment.